# Does spring kafka support auto-deserialization in consumer side with no explicit type provided?

Tags: spring, spring-kafka

I'm using spring-integration-kafka.

I have an abstract interface Event, which has dozens of concrete implementations, say, AEvent, BEvent, CEvent, etc.. And I want one only consumer listener to handle all incoming *Events, such as `fun handle(message: Message<`*>) { message.payload... }

After reading the documentation, I find no way to support auto-deserialization with no explicit type provided in consumer side.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: You know, that is unclear what kind of serialization you use there. I’m pretty sure the standard Java serialization works well here. So, what is that explicit type you are talking about?

Comment: Yes, u are correct. I wrap a Serializer & Deserializer based on standard Java serialization, and it works. Before that I expect spring-kafka has a built-in solution for this scenario.

Comment: Spring Kafka can’t make an assumption what you are expecting there. More over that is already Apache Kafka option to specify deserializer for the consumer. Therefore there is no any defaults from Spring Kafka perspective

Comment: Indeed. While for ease use of developers, more generic serializers may also be introduced just like what spring-data-redis library did.

Comment: Sure! Contribution is welcome! We do what the best for Framework but don’t overhead it with unexpected functionality. And sometimes, of course, we may just miss something. That’s why we communicate with you, community, to get direct feedback ASAP

Answer (score 0):

Using JdkSerializationRedisSerializer from spring-data-redis meet my requirements.

`public class GenericObjectSerializer implements Serializer<Object> {
  private final JdkSerializationRedisSerializer serializer =
      new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer();
}`


`public class GenericObjectDeserializer implements Deserializer<Object> {
  private final JdkSerializationRedisSerializer serializer =
      new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer();
}`